# Understanding kafka broker vs zookeper

Tags: apache-kafka

I notice that when sending messages to kafka (a producer) the samples show connecting to port 9092 -- writing directly to a broker.  When consuming the examples show connecting to port 2181, presumably zookeeper.

The latter makes sense--I want to read from "the cluster", letting zookeeper figure out which broker the client should communicate with, and managing such things as knowing who's alive/dead in the cluster.

Why wouldn't publish/writes work the same way, i.e. write to "the cluster" (via zookeeper)?

Am I understanding this correctly, that for producing I'm bypassing zookeeper (cluster knowledge) and must know producer nodes (and presumably figure out what to do if one fails)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "high level consumer" of Kafka uses Zookeeper to keep track of which partitions each member in a consumer group is consuming and sometimes to track which offsets were read in which partition. Since access to Zookeeper is required, we may as well use it to figure out where are the brokers...

In the new consumer (coming soon in the next release), Zookeeper is no longer needed, and consumers connect directly to brokers, just like producers currently do.